# What bug is going on on my command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've got a strange bug with this `/clone` command here:

[image]

As you see here, this is one of these Minecraft moving machines with commands blocks. These are pretty difficult to be made (coordinate and etc.) and I don't want to destruct this whole prototype to make a new one. A last detail before the question: before `~-4`, I've put `~-3`, but it doesn't seem to work.

My question is: How can I repair this bug without having to destroy the whole machine?

Comment: Just a rough guess, but I think you may have possibly confused the code by putting in too many `~` placeholders.

Comment: @Ben No that isn't the problem. If you are confused, the extra 3 tildes are for where the cloned object is moved too

Comment: The command in question had no problem when I ran it in my world. Here it is: `/clone ~ ~1 ~-4 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~-1 replace move`
It should be exactly the same as the one in your world

Comment: If you activate again, does the time in the output change? The output not changing whatsoever is akin to the command block not being activated properly.

Comment: Just a wild guess -- are there any blocks carrying commands in the region that you want to clone? Maybe there is a faulty command, which causes Minecraft to show a totally irrelevant error message for this command block when it is actually related to another command block.

Comment: No, there are not any command blocks where I want the machine to pass, but there are other command blocks in the machine that make it moves...

Answer (score 1):

Are you pressing enter or done when finishing? Are you activating this new command block? If you haven't, then that might be the old output.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the "old output" thing in commands blocks?

Comment: If you used ctrl, when taking this block with middle mouse button, it might ave old output from thr block you "taken" it from.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you have extra space before *replace*. Can't know for sure, since you didn't copy the command to your question correctly. (screenshots are bad, copy commands, then put them after four spaces in your question)

Comment: [Comparing the image with the same command with only one space, this does appear to be the case.](http://i.imgur.com/HtzbxX1.png) The command would normally still run, but because the source and destination overlap, and the "move" parameter which would normally allow for this is no longer counted, the command should give a "Source and destination can not overlap" error.